# How can I add hex code to an HTML element (inline style) with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple class which receives an element, finds it's color in RGB, then converts it to HEX. This works but when I add it to the element it doesn't work Like so:

```
import * as colorConvert from "color-convert"; // a package to convert RGB to hex
export default class Darken {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  hex() {
    const rgb = window.getComputedStyle(this.element).color;
    const exp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
    const matches = exp.exec(rgb);
    const rgbCode = matches[1];

    const [r, g, b] = rgbCode.split(", ");

    return colorConvert.rgb.hex(r, g, b);
  }

  changeTheStylesheet() {
    const newColor = `#${this.hex()}`; // This gives me the hex code that I want #010300
    console.log(newColor); // It's as I want it in the console

    this.element.style.color = newColor; // But here it gets shown in RGB rgb(1, 3, 0)
  }
}
```

I want to use the hex code not the RGB.
Thanks.

Comment: _"But here it gets shown in RGB rgb(1, 3, 0)"_ - where _exactly_ is "here"? Are you talking about inspecting the element in your browser dev tools? Those often show you _computed_ values, that don't necessarily use the same notation as was used when the property was set. Check what options your browser's dev tools offer in that regard, sometimes there's an option to force to display them in the notation they were set in. _"I want to use the hex code not the RGB"_  - you did, so basically there's all good here. If this becomes an actual issue somewhere, apart from debugging, then explain how.

Comment: keep in mind, to add a style in-line means to write it in the HTML element. When you use JS you are targeting the object via the DOM and changing the object's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because style property is bound to return color code in RGB format only.

Comment: So what do you think I should use? I want to use the hex code because I need it

Comment: You can only represent it somewhere using your convertRGBToHex function but you can't change the behaviour of style.color property.